# How can I listen for changes in the Django database?

Tags: django, signals

I have two separate Django projects.

Project B shares project A's database by referencing project A's database in it's models Meta class (db_table). Otherwise the projects are completely separate and run in different containers.

I want to execute a function in Project A after Project B creates or updates a Model field in the shared database.

I have tried using Model signals (post_save) in Project A, but it does not trigger when the Model field is saved in Project B when it is created or updated.

How can I pass a signal from Project B to Project A to execute code in Project A, without writing the functionality I want to execute into Project B?

Or how can I listen for changes in the database in Project A?

Comment: I think this is API task. Project B generates a signal -> function FB in B receives the signal and calls function FA in project A via url like http://<project_A.com>/waiting_for_signal -> FA calls what your need there.

Answer (score 0):

from my reinvestigation of the django official doc....signals are designed to work within a project... that means they work very well across diff applications so far as they are within the same project.

Comment: That's right, !